# Set LinearLayout visible and call getBottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

In my app, I have a `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` whose visibility is set on `GONE`.
I need to make it visible and then have my ScrollView scroll to the bottom of the LinearLayout.
For this I'm using this code:

```
mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mLinearLayout.getBottom());
```

This however, does not work. When the ScrollView is asked to scroll the LinearLayout still returns 0 on getBottom().

So when this is called for the first time, the LinearLayout is visible, but the scrollview has not scrolled.
When it is called for a second time, it does scroll down to the right position.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your smmothScrollTo method inside a new thread like this:

```
     mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,mLinearLayout.getBottom());

                }
            });
```

Comment: also +1 for this, I did not know about the 'post' method